# How to acquire a user based token from Azure Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have an Azure Active Directory and in my Web Api I have a piece of code that I can get a token from Azure Graph Api using the Application that I have registered with Azure and a Client Certificate.
Here is the code that I use right now:

```
public static string AcquireServiceToken()
{
    var authority = string.Format(_authority, "common");
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

    var result = authContext.AcquireToken(_serviceTokenResourceId, new ClientAssertionCertificate(_serviceTokenClientId, GetClientCertificate(_certThumbprint)));
    return result.AccessToken;
}
```

This snippet of code works just fine, now what I need is a more specific token which has logged-in user's context, so basically I need to be able to pass in a username and password and get a Graph token back from Azure.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AcquireToken has another overload that takes in a UserCredential object and U assume you could use that (You will need the TenantId of the Active Directory that the users you need to acquire the tokens for)

Your function will look something like this: (Please fill in the _variables with your own application information)

```
public static string AcquireTokenWithoutUserCredentials(string userName, string password)
{
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format(_authority, _userTokenTenantId));
    var userCreds = new UserCredential(userName, password);
    var result = authContext.AcquireToken(_resourceId, _userTokenClientId, userCreds);
    return result.AccessToken;
}
```

Looking at your code, looks like you have a multi tenant scenario, in which you use "common" as TenatName, which I'm not sure how/if it will work using the code I pasted here but give it a try ...

Comment: The code above should not be used with a confidential client (e.g. anything with its one credentials, like the web API mentioned here). It should not work for a confidential client, and if it works by any chance, it will stop working soon. I'll provide an alternative answer for the intended service side flow

Comment: This works fine for us and we use this in all our integration tests to get a user token... I haven't tested it in multi-tenant scenarios though...

Comment: Aram, are you using native clients or web clients? As I mentioned above and in the other answer, the username/password flow is supposed to work only with native clients (with limitations). There are cases in which it works also for confidential clients (web apps) but it is not supported and such cases will be fixed soon - as in, it will no longer work.

Comment: in my case, we use that in our automation tests project, where we need to get a user token to be able to call our Api...

Comment: in our case we need to get the first token in our unit tests to be able to test the Web Api

Answer (score 2):

A web API can access another web API (in this case, the Graph) as the current user by obtaining a new token via the onbehalfof flow. See https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof for an example. The direct use of username and password is not recommended, credentials should never be collected outside of Azure AD own pages, and in this specific case it would not work (or will stop working soon)

Comment: So how do we do automated API tests where it needs a graph token with user context? we need a way to get a token for a given Azure Ad object_Id so that it can pass our Api's Authz ...

Comment: If the client of your web api is a native client, you can use the u/p flow to get the first token for calling your API - the one for the graph is obtained from that first token.