# Authenticate to azure subscription with local credentials (non-AD)

Tags: c#, azure

I have a set of non-active directory azure credentials: `user@domain.com` and `password123` and I can't figure out how to authenticate with them. I have working code that obtains the access token using an app registration service into which I pass the subscription ID, tenant ID, app ID, and secret key but I can't figure out how to obtain the same token with just my username and password.

This [blog post](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/) makes it sound like authenticating via username and password is possible (although perhaps not recommended :) but it's all about using ADAL which my IT department tells me is not configured for our subscription. I've tried using the code from it in conjunction with some of my existing code to do something like this:

```
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
var userCred = new UserCredential("user@domain.com", "password123");
var result = authContext.AcquireToken(string resource, string clientId, userCred);

result.Wait();
if (result.Result == null)
    throw new AuthenticationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");

credentials = new TokenCredentials(result.Result.AccessToken);
```

But I can't figure out what to use for `resource` or `clientId` and I'm not sure  `https://login.windows.net/` is the correct value for `authority` either since my code only works against the app registration running on a subscription with ADAL setup. I can't even find any resources on local-credential-based authentication through code. Is this possible?

Comment: Note, you probably shouldn't do this, as the blog post also mentions. Anyway, https://login.windows.net is the general AD of Microsoft. You want to use https://login.windows.net/<your-tenant-guid>/.

Comment: Look at this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828334/how-to-acquire-a-user-based-token-from-azure-graph-api/32828544#32828544

Comment: @Aram Thanks for that link. Unfortunately, that answer appears to assume AD is set up which my IT guys are telling me is not the case. They also would like to keep it that way, I guess.

Comment: @sirdank without playing with the tenant settings and manifests you wont be able to get a user token when you have a username password from code.