# By any means can we get access token from Azure ADAL by passing username and pass in http request

Tags: azure, active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal

I don't need Microsoft Login screen.

If I am already having username and password with me ,
can't I just pass them using Http client and get the authentication token.

Is it possible , please suggest.

Comment: Have you fixed this issue now? If you still have the problem about using the **resource owner password credential flow**, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: No not able to resolve it.. @FeiXue-MSFT

Comment: Can you suggest any working sample for this implementation..

Answer (score 2):

The Azure AD supports various flow about OAuth 2.0. To acquire the access token with username and password directly, we can interact with **resource owner password credential flow**. However this scenario should be used carefully since it may leak the password. You can refer this flow about specification from [rfc6749#page-37](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-37).

And to implement this flow using C#, you can refer this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/09/25/resource-owner-password-credentials-grant-in-azure-ad-oauth/).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, it is possible but not recommended (See comments from Philippe below).

The ability to get a token when you have a user name and password is extremely limited.
You might be able to do this in rare scenarios when your device is not able to prompt the AAD Auth page, or in cases when it is a native app/automation tests and etc.

Please see this post for the limitations and workarounds:

http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/

Also look at this answer from me here, where I made it to work for our automation tests, but Vibronet has comments that, this solution will stop working, but not sure it has happened yet or not.

[How to acquire a user based token from Azure Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828334/how-to-acquire-a-user-based-token-from-azure-graph-api)

Comment: are you kidding me? http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart_authentication.html?highlight=UserPassCredentials

Comment: @4c74356b41 Yeah, As I mentioned I got it working with User/Pass credential for now, but as their PM (Vibronet) mentioned, it will eventually stop working except for certain scenarios that they cannot use the AAD Login page...

Comment: so the answer is 'yes', not 'no'

Comment: @4c74356b41 Well they don't want the clients go that route as they want to stop it from happening. They were even surprised that it works somehow..

Comment: understanding the limitation of a method and not being able to do something are 2 completely different things

Comment: Azure AD does support the Resource Owner Password Credentials flow for native client application. What @vibronet is saying is that this flow for _confidential_ clients is what is not supported. That said, there are a bunch of reasons why it is not a good idea to use the ROPC flow, for both security and usability reasons--so it is very strongly recommended that you do not use this except for a very limited subset of scenarios.